# Перебор цикла в обратном порядке

Tags: javascript, циклы

Вот цикл перебора. Подскажите, как сделать перебор в обратном порядке, а то я что-то ни как понять не могу

```
for (var i = 0; i < Name.length; i++) {
    document.write(Name[i].join(" ") + "<br>");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
for (var i = Name.length-1; i >= 0; i--)   
{  
    document.write(Name[i].join(" ") + "<br>");
}
```